# PHP echo link, adding more to it

Tags: php, iframe, echo, lightbox, prettyphoto

I am setting up a wordpress website and want to alter a plugin to work with another so that when a news link is clicked it will open in a lightbox using an iframe. I believe the following instances to be where the link is made.

```
<a href="<?php echo $link;  ?>
```

I am looking to add the following to the link, at the end.

```
?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]"
```

I am unsure of how to combine the two. I am hoping by doing so that I correctly located and understood what needed to be changed. If you want to see the full PHP file I have added it to http://pastebin.com/sFqSb1Ha

While I wouldn't mind someone telling me the answer, I would be happy to just be pointed in the right direction for the knowledge I need to study to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that there are a lot of `$link` echos in the code you provided. To apply that attrubute for all, you may set `$link` before, like:

```
$link = $link . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]';
```

(Note that `"` at the end is missing, because it's already provided in `href=""`).

But if you want to use it for a single link, try

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" ...
```

There is just a little problem. If in `$link` there are parameters in URL, it will fail, because any other param must start with `&`, and we have `?iframe` there. So it's good to check, whetever the `?` sign occurs in `$link` or not.

```
if (strpos($link, '?') > 0)
    $link = $link . '&iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]';
else
    $link = $link . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]';
```

Comment: Your answer both worked and was extremely educational. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%"' . 'rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]"';  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel='prettyPhoto[iframes]'"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo $link ."?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%\" ". " rel=\"prettyPhoto[iframes]\" ";  ?>
```

for echo use " you can use other varible in this